# Axis2 webservice with multiple soap bindings

Tags: soap, binding, apache-axis

When i add the service via SoaPUI, it returns with 2 bindings.(soap11 and soap12). They have both same methods but only 12 works.I would like to have only a soap12 shown and not soap11 binding. The services xml file is below. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
<service name="UserOperations" >
<Description>
    Please Type your service description here
</Description>
<messageReceivers>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
    <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>
<parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.webservices.UserOperations</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting

```
<parameter name=”disableSOAP12”>true</parameter>
```

in your service.xml

More info [here](http://wso2.com/library/3821/).

Answer (score 0):

Edit the locked flag in **axis2.xml** from true to false as given below

```
<parameter name="disableSOAP12" locked="false">false</parameter>
```

This will allow the user the override disableSOAP12 in services.xml in service level.Then add the below line in **services.xml**

```
<parameter name="disableSOAP12">true</parameter>
```